# What season was it during the Siege of Luthadel?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

I'm pretty sure I'm just having trouble finding a quote, but I can't figure out what season it's supposed to be at the start of the Siege of Luthadel.  It seems like the siege ends in the winter, due to the snow when the koloss attack, but I can't figure out either exactly how long the siege lasted or what time of year it was throughout.

Comment: brassily from the time they kill the lord ruler their is no more seasons.

Comment: @Himarm Really?  Do you have a reference for that?  I definitely feel like I remember there being seasonal differences mentioned after Final Empire.

Comment: I don't think there's any direct reference to weather out of the ordinary, I think I remember Elend mentioning that it was cold just before his final battle.. But that's all.

Comment: Once the lord ruler dies they ash starts to dump faster and faster as the world slowly spins out of control so the seasons essentially get stuck in whatever they were if i remember correctly

Comment: I don't know if that entirely true @Himarm, since the Ashmounts don't really go nuts until the 3rd book.  The mists are the big weather concern in the 2nd book.  But the climate is alien enough that I don't think seasons are really recognizable.  At least, not to me.

Comment: @Radhil I'd totally be cool with a good frame challenge of the form "seasons in Scadrial don't work like that, here's some support for that idea".

Comment: @DuckTapeal - even a quick read through showed I was wrong, but found what you needed anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was fall when the siege started, and winter by the time it ended.

Relevant quote from *The Well of Ascension*, as they discuss the first two incoming armies (the third not showing till later) and propose the plan to play the two off each other:

> “Not to mention our food problems,” Dockson said. “What you propose would take time, Your Majesty. Time during which we’d be under siege, our supplies dwindling. It’s autumn right now. Winter will soon be upon us.”

Winter ending of the seige can be easily concluded by the snow on the battlefield, which even Elend has to deal with on his trip north towards Terris.